# PhysicsJS change circle radius

Tags: physicsjs

After collision of 2 dots i want they make 1 dot with double radius so my code

```
world.on("collisions:detected", function(data) {
    data.collisions[0].bodyA.mass *=2
    data.collisions[0].bodyA.radius *=2
    data.collisions[0].bodyB.mass = 0
    data.collisions[0].bodyA.recalc()
    data.collisions[0].bodyB.recalc()
})
```

Radius doesn't change and sometimes strange behavior that 2 dots dissapear at one moment.

Is my code correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a mass of zero. If you want try setting the mass to be really small.

You might also be having a problem with the renderer's views not being refreshed. This is easy, just set the `.view` on each body to `null`.

I'd also recommend making your code more general by using one of the tactics described here:
https://github.com/wellcaffeinated/PhysicsJS/wiki/Collisions

That way if you add more bodies to your simulation it'll still work. For example:

```
myCatBody.label = 'cat;
myDogBody.label = 'dog;

// query to find a collision between a body with label "cat" and a body with label "dog"
var query = Physics.query({
    $or: [
        { bodyA: { label: 'cat' }, bodyB: { label: 'dog' } }
        ,{ bodyB: { label: 'dog' }, bodyA: { label: 'cat' } }
    ]
});

// monitor collisions
world.on('collisions:detected', function( data, e ){
    // find the first collision that matches the query
    var found = Physics.util.findOne( data.collisions, query );
    if ( found ){
        found.bodyA.mass *= 2;
        found.bodyA.geometry.radius *= 2;
        found.bodyB.mass = 0.001;
        found.bodyA.view = null;
        found.bodyB.view = null;
        found.bodyA.recalc();
        found.bodyB.recalc()
    }
});
```

Comment: I need 2 dots after collision make 1 bigger. Radius change doesn't work by doing it your way.

Comment: my mistake. You need to modify the .geometry.radius property. Not the radius on the body. If you don't need bodyB then consider just removing it from the world after it collides with `world.remove()`